# Implementing Brainf*ck loops with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, brainfuck

So `i` is the instruction pointer and `ptr` is the data pointer.
I'm trying to get this right:

> [ -    if the byte at the data pointer is zero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it forward to the command after the matching ] command.
>
> ] -    if the byte at the data pointer is nonzero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it back to the command after the matching [ command.

```
 var memory = new Array();
 for ( var ptr = 0; ptr < 1000; ptr++ )
    memory[ptr] = 0;
 var ptr = 0;
 var src = document.getElementById("source").value;
 for ( var i = 0; i < src.length; i++ )
 {   
    // other code
    if ( src[i] == "[" )
        if ( memory[ptr] == 0 )
        {
            for ( var j = i; j < src.length; j++ )
                if ( src[j] == "]" )
                {
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            continue; // so we don't enter the next if
        }
    if ( src[i] == "]" )
        if ( memory[ptr] != 0 )
            for ( var k = i; k > 0; k-- )
                if ( src[k] == "[" )
                {
                    i = k;
                    break;
                }
 }
```

Everything works but trying the Hello World example with loops generates wrong output, the `[` and `]` messed up somewhere.

Any suggestions on how to fix the loop?

**Edit**

Here are the modified `if`s with the suggested nesting handlers, it now executes the Hello World example properly.

```
   if ( src[i] == "[" )
        if ( memory[ptr] == 0 )
        {
            var count = 1;
            for ( var j = i + 1; j < src.length; j++ )
            {
                if ( src[j] == "[" )
                    count++;
                if ( src[j] == "]" )
                    count--;
                if ( count == 0 )
                {
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
    if ( src[i] == "]" )
        if ( memory[ptr] != 0 )
        {
            var count = 1;
            for ( var k = i - 1; k > 0; k-- )
            {
                if ( src[k] == "]" )
                    count++;
                if ( src[k] == "[" )
                    count--;
                if ( count == 0 )
                {
                    i = k;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly handle nesting of `[` and `]`. I would do this by having a `count` variable. For example, when you encounter a `[` and need to find the matching `]`, initialize `count` to 1 and go through the characters. When you come across a `[`, increment it; on a `]`, decrement it. When `count` hits zero, you have found the matching bracket.